# Android NDK build cmake include .so library included in .aar library

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, aar

I have an *android_library.aar* file that containing *library.so* and some other resources and java files.

I imported *android_library.aar* to my project. My project uses c++ code with NDK. My problem is I can not compile C++ code that dependent with *library.so* with CMake. How could I extract *library.so* from **aar** before CMake compile? I want to include *library.so* to my C++ code directly without java. I know how to include **.so** in a project but I don't know how to do it from inside of aar.

Comment: *Very nice indeed!* I believe that **gradle** does extract the **.so** files if the **.aar** is a dependency.

Comment: I thought so. But it does not extract before cmake build. I don't know why. I searched for it and did not find any answer easy than this method.

Comment: … but in your solution the **aar** is not declared as dependency of your project, s it?

Comment: It's also must declare library as dependency. Because of Java part of library. I don't know much about dependency decleration also affecting to JNI part or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution on my own after 1-week research. I found some code from Google GVR code. But it hasn't worked for my case. I changed **build.dependsOn** to **preBuild.dependsOn** then it worked. It might help some people in the future.

**Here is the example code:**

In the module's build.gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ["jniLibs"]
    }
}

task extractSo(type: Copy) {
    println 'Extracting *.so file(s)....'

    from zipTree("${project.rootDir}/ModuleName/ModuleName.aar")
    into "${project.rootDir}/${project.name}/src/main/jniLibs/"
    include "jni/**/*.so"

    eachFile {
        def segments = it.getRelativePath().getSegments() as List
        println segments
        it.setPath(segments.tail().join("/"))
        return it
    }
    includeEmptyDirs = false
}

preBuild.dependsOn extractSo
```

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays this is possible without much boiler plate.
Prerequisite is that your AAR file includes a `prefab` folder.
So the library maintainer needs to properly set things up.

If this is the case then it's as easy as adding following to `app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    // ...
    buildFeatures {
        prefab true // extracts native libraries from AAR for usage in C++
    }
}
```

Then in `CMakeLists.txt` you can find and register the lib:

```
# Locate the native library:
find_package(ModuleName REQUIRED CONFIG)        
# Replace ModuleName with the actual name of your module.
# It can be found in `prefab/prefab.json` file of your AAR.

target_link_libraries(
        app
        ModuleName::nameOfSoFileWithoutFileEnding
)
```

Example with the OpenCV AAR library on Maven:

```
# ...
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED CONFIG)    

target_link_libraries(
        app
        OpenCV::opencv_java4
)
```

This will register `opencv_java4.so` that is part of the AAR file. The C++ header files would be added as well.